# apache basic auth breaks rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, authentication

rewriting works fine until we add auth to htaccess. Is auth formatted correctly? Why would rewrite work before adding auth?

Request params at the site controller with no auth:

```
[id] => 433    [type] => city
```

Params after auth added and the user authenticated:

```
[site/query]
```

Sample query url that works without auth:

```
http://www.website.com/site/query?type=city&id=433
```

The .htaccess with basic auth at the bottom:

```
# any visits not coming from this official URL should be rerouted; AJAX cross-domain, www.website.com is not the same as our.company.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# route all requests that are NOT static files, through index.php to make the /nice/urls/ work
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

# disable file listings for directories
Options -Indexes

# disable the fetching of .phtm
<Files ~ "\.phtml$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password required"
AuthUserFile /maps/scorp/main/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Is there a missing RewriteRule before the Auth instructions? There are 2 RewriteCond without any RewriteRule after, at the end just before auth instructions?

Answer (score 1):

I've got no answer to your nice questions but I hope I found a solution. :)

IMHO in your *.htaccess* the authorisation will take the advantage. It's a kinda tricky but you can break the priority by enclosing the "Require valid-user" directive into block <Files>. E.g.:

```
<Files "*.phtml">
    Require valid-user
</Files>
```